# Janus Graph example-remotegraph Error: Unknown external index backend: jgex

Tags: java, janusgraph

I work with JanusGraph0.5.3 for some test on windows. I want to use Java client to connect the gremlin-server.
I launch the server

```
gremlin-server.bat
```

It seems to be successful

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Users/Lenovo/Downloads/janusgraph-0.5.3/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Users/Lenovo/Downloads/janusgraph-0.5.3/lib/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
log4j: Using URL [file:/D:/Users/Lenovo/Downloads/janusgraph-0.5.3/conf/gremlin-server/log4j-server.properties] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Reading configuration from URL file:/D:/Users/Lenovo/Downloads/janusgraph-0.5.3/conf/gremlin-server/log4j-server.properties
log4j: Parsing for [root] with value=[INFO, A1, A2].
log4j: Level token is [INFO].
log4j: Category root set to INFO
log4j: Parsing appender named "A1".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "A1".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "A1".
log4j: Setting property [file] to [D:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\janusgraph-0.5.3\logs/gremlin-server.log].
log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [INFO].
log4j: setFile called: D:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\janusgraph-0.5.3\logs/gremlin-server.log, true
log4j: setFile ended
log4j: Parsed "A1" options.
log4j: Parsing appender named "A2".
log4j: Parsing layout options for "A2".
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n].
log4j: End of parsing for "A2".
log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [INFO].
log4j: Parsed "A2" options.
log4j: Finished configuring.
0    [main] INFO  com.jcabi.manifests.Manifests  - 113 attributes loaded from 263 stream(s) in 98ms, 113 saved, 3649 ignored: ["Agent-Class", "Ant-Version", "Archiver-Version", "Automatic-Module-Name", "Bnd-LastModified", "Boot-Class-Path", "Branch", "Build-Date", "Build-Host", "Build-Id", "Build-Java-Version", "Build-Jdk", "Build-Jdk-Spec", "Build-Job", "Build-Number", "Build-Timestamp", "Build-Version", "Built-At", "Built-By", "Built-Date", "Built-OS", "Built-On", "Built-Status", "Bundle-ActivationPolicy", "Bundle-Activator", "Bundle-BuddyPolicy", "Bundle-Category", "Bundle-ClassPath", "Bundle-ContactAddress", "Bundle-Description", "Bundle-DocURL", "Bundle-License", "Bundle-ManifestVersion", "Bundle-Name", "Bundle-NativeCode", "Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment", "Bundle-SymbolicName", "Bundle-Vendor", "Bundle-Version", "Can-Redefine-Classes", "Change", "Class-Path", "Copyright", "Created-By", "DSTAMP", "DynamicImport-Package", "Eclipse-BuddyPolicy", "Eclipse-ExtensibleAPI", "Embed-Dependency", "Embed-Transitive", "Export-Package", "Extension-Name", "Extension-name", "Fragment-Host", "Gradle-Version", "Gremlin-Lib-Paths", "Gremlin-Plugin-Dependencies", "Gremlin-Plugin-Paths", "Ignore-Package", "Implementation-Build", "Implementation-Build-Date", "Implementation-Title", "Implementation-URL", "Implementation-Vendor", "Implementation-Vendor-Id", "Implementation-Version", "Import-Package", "Include-Resource", "JCabi-Build", "JCabi-Date", "JCabi-Version", "Java-Vendor", "Java-Version", "Main-Class", "Manifest-Version", "Maven-Version", "Module-Email", "Module-Origin", "Module-Owner", "Module-Source", "Multi-Release", "Originally-Created-By", "Os-Arch", "Os-Name", "Os-Version", "Package", "Premain-Class", "Private-Package", "Provide-Capability", "Require-Bundle", "Require-Capability", "Scm-Connection", "Scm-Revision", "Scm-Url", "Specification-Title", "Specification-Vendor", "Specification-Version", "TODAY", "TSTAMP", "Time-Zone-Database-Version", "Tool", "X-Compile-Elasticsearch-Snapshot", "X-Compile-Elasticsearch-Version", "X-Compile-Lucene-Version", "X-Compile-Source-JDK", "X-Compile-Target-JDK", "hash", "implementation-version", "mode", "package", "service", "url", "version"]
1    [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - 3.4.6
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----

81   [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Configuring Gremlin Server from D:\Users\Lenovo\Downloads\janusgraph-0.5.3\conf\gremlin-server\gremlin-server.yaml
122  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  - Configured Metrics ConsoleReporter configured with report interval=180000ms
123  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  - Configured Metrics CsvReporter configured with report interval=180000ms to fileName=/tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv
160  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  - Configured Metrics JmxReporter configured with domain= and agentId=
161  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  - Configured Metrics Slf4jReporter configured with interval=180000ms and loggerName=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings$Slf4jReporterMetrics
610  [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.configuration.builder.ReadConfigurationBuilder  - Set default timestamp provider MICRO
618  [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.graphdb.idmanagement.UniqueInstanceIdRetriever  - Generated unique-instance-id=c0a8110121912-DESKTOP-P5265PE1
627  [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend  - Initiated backend operations thread pool of size 32
678  [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog  - Loaded unidentified ReadMarker start time 2021-01-25T01:28:22.797Z into org.janusgraph.diskstorage.log.kcvs.KCVSLog$MessagePuller@4e70a728
679  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Graph [graph] was successfully configured via [conf/janusgraph-inmemory.properties].
679  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor  - Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool named with pattern gremlin-*
712  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor  - Initialized GremlinExecutor and preparing GremlinScriptEngines instances.
2658 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor  - Initialized gremlin-groovy GremlinScriptEngine and registered metrics
2660 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor  - A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[standardjanusgraph[inmemory:[127.0.0.1]], standard]
2672 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.OpLoader  - Adding the standard OpProcessor.
2674 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.OpLoader  - Adding the session OpProcessor.
2729 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.OpLoader  - Adding the traversal OpProcessor.
2735 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor  - Initialized cache for TraversalOpProcessor with size 1000 and expiration time of 600000 ms
2809 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Executing start up LifeCycleHook
2818 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Executed once at startup of Gremlin Server.
2822 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - idleConnectionTimeout was set to 0 which resolves to 0 seconds when configuring this value - this feature will be disabled
2823 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - keepAliveInterval was set to 0 which resolves to 0 seconds when configuring this value - this feature will be disabled
2825 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - The org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0 serialization class is deprecated.
2861 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0
2862 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - The org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0 serialization class is deprecated.
2864 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo-stringd with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0
2880 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
2880 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
2882 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - The org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0 serialization class is deprecated.
2882 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+gryo with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0
2883 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - The org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoLiteMessageSerializerV1d0 serialization class is deprecated.
2884 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+gryo-lite with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoLiteMessageSerializerV1d0
2884 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - The org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0 serialization class is deprecated.
2884 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+gryo-stringd with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0
2887 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV2d0
2887 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - application/json already has org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0 configured - it will not be replaced by org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV2d0, change order of serialization configuration if this is not desired.
2891 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v1.0+json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerGremlinV1d0
2892 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.AbstractChannelizer  - application/json already has org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0 configured - it will not be replaced by org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0, change order of serialization configuration if this is not desired.
3198 [gremlin-server-boss-1] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Gremlin Server configured with worker thread pool of 1, gremlin pool of 16 and boss thread pool of 1.
3198 [gremlin-server-boss-1] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Channel started at port 8182.
```

However, when I execute the example-remotegraph

```
mvn clean install
mvn exec:java -pl :example-remotegraph
```

I got an exception.  `Unknown external index backend: jgex`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------< org.janusgraph:example-remotegraph >-----------------
[INFO] Building Example-RemoteGraph: Example with RemoteGraph 0.5.3
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) @ example-remotegraph ---
0    [org.janusgraph.example.RemoteGraphApp.main()] INFO  org.janusgraph.example.RemoteGraphApp  - opening graph
542  [org.janusgraph.example.RemoteGraphApp.main()] INFO  org.janusgraph.example.RemoteGraphApp  - creating schema
972  [org.janusgraph.example.RemoteGraphApp.main()] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Connection  - Created new connection for ws://127.0.0.1:8182/gremlin
977  [org.janusgraph.example.RemoteGraphApp.main()] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.Connection  - Created new connection for ws://127.0.0.1:8182/gremlin
978  [org.janusgraph.example.RemoteGraphApp.main()] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ConnectionPool  - Opening connection pool on Host{address=127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:8182, hostUri=ws://127.0.0.1:8182/gremlin} with core size of 2
1270 [org.janusgraph.example.RemoteGraphApp.main()] ERROR org.janusgraph.example.GraphApp  - org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: Unknown external index backend: jgex
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.ResponseException: Unknown external index backend: jgex
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(CompletableFuture.java:375)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:1947)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet.one(ResultSet.java:119)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ResultSet$1.hasNext(ResultSet.java:171)
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:115)
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
        at org.janusgraph.example.RemoteGraphApp.createSchema(RemoteGraphApp.java:188)
        at org.janusgraph.example.GraphApp.runApp(GraphApp.java:294)
        at org.janusgraph.example.RemoteGraphApp.main(RemoteGraphApp.java:194)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I think I followed the guide correctly, how to solve it?

Comment: I also have the error "Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings" did you find a solution?

Comment: Facing same issue